# console application wait for keyup

Tags: c#, console

I´m currently working on a roguelike in c#.
The world, player etc. are rendered inside of a console. But when there are too many changes in the console, it lags.
To bypass this, I´m trying to let programm wait for the player to un-press the key the player is pressing.
Anyone has an idea on how to make this?
Bad, that there isn´t something like `Console.ReadKeyUp()`.

```
while(Console.KeyAvailable){
}
```

seems not to work...

Here´s a bit of code:

```
public void move(){
            if(!MainClass.loading){
                switch(Console.ReadKey().Key){
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad8:
                        //walk up
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad4:
                        //walk left
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad6:
                        //walk right
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                        //walk down
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad7:
                        //walk left up
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad9:
                        //walk right up
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                        //walk left down
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:
                        //walk right down
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad5:
                        //eat
                        break;
                }

            }

        }
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: The console is for easy but basic input and output functionality. Write a GUI for a game instead. (It's not DOS days!)

Comment: By console you mean *the* console (text I/O)?! How exactly a game's world is rendered inside a console?!

Comment: It´s rendered like this: http://puu.sh/2whk6

Comment: @AlvinWong nothing wrong with making a text-based console game.  The days of ascii art may be behind us but it's no reason to not long for a bit of nostalgia.

Comment: @Hobbit9797 - can you give us some more information about the structure of your program?  Are you using a message handler/dispatcher?  Show some example code of how you are doing things.  How are you currently handling key input?

Comment: @J... The point is, there are usually no events like KeyDown and KeyUp because a text console is more focused on getting text inputs rather than raw keyboard events. Also, very often, using a text console yields low performance, especially when updating the display. (Unless you use lower level Windows APIs via P/Invoke)

Comment: @AlvinWong yes, but that doesn't mean that you can't throw a hidden WndProc into your application.  It may mean a heavy refactor, however, depending on how he has structured the program thusfar, however, so it is important to understand how it has been written to suggest ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Seems like a lot of downvotes, I guess because he dared to make a console game. Problem is with high horses, is it's a long way to fall!

Answer (score 2):

Without refactoring this application into an event-driven format (hidden window with message loop, etc) your best bet is probably to dig through the various functions available in the WinAPI.  Something like this may work:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte [] lpKeyState);
```

You can use this function to query the full keyboard state - it returns a 256-byte array containing the state of the keyboard.  See : [here for more](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeyboardstate) and some examples.

You might also, for example, use `Console.ReadKey()` and then block until `GetKeyState()` returns a low-order `0` for the key in question :

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern short GetKeyState(VirtualKeyStates nVirtKey);
```

See : [here for more](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetKeyState.html) and examples.

MSDN : [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)