# Need a piece of code to check if a key is continously pressed in console application

Tags: c#, console

I have been trying to come up with a solution to make a code that can check if the button is being held for 3 seconds. Wanted to make a Quit method, that checks if the escape key is being held down, and after one second it writes Quiting. then 1 seconds later Quiting.. then again, 1 second later Quiting... and then it runs the Environment.Exit(0); to quit the console application. If at any point the person stops pressing the escape key, the method finishes. When i used IF selection 3 times, after every Thread.Sleep(1000) to check for the escape key either all of them went true or all false for the

`If (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)` code.

Are they being calculated the same time, because they had the same statement in them? Or how can i stop the method when the key is released?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882499/console-application-wait-for-keyup.

Comment: The `Console` class is not suited to asynchronous user input. It depends on the stdin stream. Your code is reading three `Escape` keys in a row, because after a short delay, Windows automatically starts repeating the held key. You'll need to use the native API per the marked duplicate to read the keyboard state asynchronously.